# Use data attributes in laravel form select

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

How would i add a data attribute to a laravel `{{Form::select}}` array?

For example, I want each of my options to look like this

```
<option value="1" data-days="182">6 Months</option>
<option value="2" data-days="365">1 Year</option>
```

How do I add the data attribute in the following select array?

**Days Table**

```
id | days |   name
1  |  182 |   6 Months
2  |  365 |   1 Year
```

**View**

```
{{Form::select('amount_of_days', $days, null, ['placeholder' => 'Amount of days'])}}
```

Comment: Use simple foreach instead then

Comment: I was hoping to keep it in the format above, but if there is no other way then I will resort to this. Thanks

Comment: There is no way to do like you want , `$days`  must be either `value` or `key => value` pair no other option

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For this requiment you need to create the `<option>` with loop and simply html

```
<select name="amount_of_days" placeholder="Amount of days">
    @foreach($days as $val)
        <option value="{{ $val['id'] }}" data-days="{{ $val['days'] }}"> {{ $val['name'] }}<option>
    @endforeach
</select>
```

Answer (score 2):

The best way to set the custom value to the form::select is by using the attribute parameter of form::select function.

**controller.php**

```
$contact_options = Contact::all();

$contact_attributes = $contact_options->mapWithKeys(function ($item) {
    return [$item->id => ['data-otherInfo' => $item->otherInfo]];
})->toArray();

$contact_options = $contact_options->pluck('name', 'id')->toArray();
```

**blade.php**

```
{!! Form::select('contact_id', $contact_options, old('contact_id', null), ['class'=>"form-control", 'id'=>"contact_id", 'required' => 'required'], $contact_attributes) !!}
```